# showing the identity of a hyperbolic function

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

Need to just verify that I'm doing this one right.

1. $$\sinh{2x} = 2 \cdot \sinh{x} \cdot \cosh{x}$$
   $$= 2 \cdot \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} \cdot \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$$
   $$= \frac{2 \cdot e^{2x} - e^{-2x}}{4}$$

$$= \sinh{2x}$$

Is that right?

Comment: Well, since you began with $\;\sinh2x\;$ , it is just logical you end up with that... Anyway, the whole process is *almost*  correct: one line before the last one it must be $\;4\;$ in the denominator. . Also, change that exponent $\;-2\;$ to $\;-x\;$ in the second line of calculations.

Comment: That's still wrong in that denominator: $\;\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac14\;$ ...

Comment: You need parens around the exponential in you second last line.  Then the calculation will be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good, but it's not laid out well.

An identity can be verified by transforming one side into the other or both into the same expression. In this case it's easier starting from the right-hand side, which is essentially what you do:
\begin{align}
2\sinh x\cosh x
&=2\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\\[6px]
&=\frac{(e^x-e^{-x})(e^x+e^{-x})}{2}\\[6px]
&=\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2}\\[6px]
&=\sinh2x
\end{align}
using $(e^x)^2=e^{2x}$ and $(e^{-x})^2=e^{-2x}$.